# The Firebase crash reporting on iOS not send the report after the crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have configured the Firebase Crash Reporting. When I test it with code:

```
assert(true);
```

The report was sending.

When I use the next code for the test crash the app:

```
NSArray *array = @[@(123),@(312)];
array[5];
```

The report is not sending. I'm confused(

All code adds into AppDelegate after the

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this scenario and it worked fine for me. let me explain it in two steps.

Step 1:

```
NSArray *array = @[@(123),@(312)];
array[5];
```

add the code in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and after that, build the application. It will crash for sure.

Step 2: Stop the application and open the simulator and run the application from the simulator not from Xcode.

Step 3:

```
// NSArray *array = @[@(123),@(312)];
   // array[5];
```

comment the code which is causing the crash and run it from the Xcode.

if all work well then this message will be shown "Firebase Crash Reporting: Crash successfully uploaded" in the console of Xcode.

Hope it helps. 
Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Oh! 

I have looked into main.m file and terrified!! It appears the previous developer catch all exceptions to output them in the log and returns the value 0. 

When I remove this code, all report have sent successfully. 

Another proof those miracles do not happen.

Comment: Can you please tell how to properly configure Build Phases  script? 
Should I add the JSON-file into the project or paste on any folder? 

My script: 
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:*******************

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/MyProject/ServiceAccount.json"

And the file in src/MyProject dir

Comment: # Replace this path with the path to the key you just downloaded
JSON_FILE=${SRCROOT}/*****/ServiceAccount.json
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file

GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:**********:ios:*********

defaults write com.google.SymbolUpload version -integer 1
# creates file if it does not exist
JSON=$(cat "${JSON_FILE}")
/usr/bin/plutil -replace "app_${GOOGLE_APP_ID//:/_}" -json "${JSON}" "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym

Comment: I use it only once so did not know much about it. And the above is my script. Which works for me

Comment: In first line    "JSON_FILE=${SRCROOT}/*****/ServiceAccount.json"    If your JSON file is in the project folder  "XYZ"  then you only need this   "JSON_FILE=${SRCROOT}/XYZ/ServiceAccount.json" or if it is in a subFolder of XYZ the like this      "JSON_FILE=${SRCROOT}/XYZ/subFolder/ServiceAccount.json"

Comment: and set you GOOGLE_APP_ID . And that is it. Hope it helps